# Extracting a multiple lines from a file in AIX

Tags: unix, aix

I have a requirement where I need to fetch multiple lines from a file in AIX server based on a input string.

For e.g. If I have below statement inside a file. I want to fetch the lines which starts from **INSERT** and should keep fetching the lines till I encounter first semicolon.

```
select date from student ;

insert into abc
select * from abc;
```

So my output should look like as shown below:

```
insert into abc
select * from abc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` to do the job for you

```
sed '/<pattern1>/,/<pattern2>/!d;/<pattern2>/q'
```

Here `d` is for deleting the lines which do !not fall within the range, then `q` quitting the first time it encounters the end of the range.

```
sed '/insert/,/;/!d;/select/q' test.txt
```

or

```
sed '/insert/,/;/!d;/;/q' test.txt
```

o/p -

```
insert into abc
select * from abc;
```

Comment: This solution will print all the insert statement if it lies before the encountering second pattern i.e. the `;`